# Is there a downloadable data set of words for personality-descriptive or (human related adjectives) adjectives?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am conducting a project using python NLTK, but need to differentiate between adjectives which are non-human related and those human-related ones.
For example words like "polite", "thoughtful", and "intelligent" are mostly human-related rather than "good", "wonderful", "excellent", "great". I am looking for extracting first category.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow***.

Answer (score 1):

You can test several approaches for this problem. First and not the most accurate is to use this link [List of adjectives for human](http://adjective1.com/for-human/)

The second approach is checking some ontologies (such as wordnet) to find a relation between adjectives and human entity.

And the third and hardest method is to find a POS tagged corpus and find adjectives used with any entity that refers to a human.

Comment: That's very limited

Comment: Then use wordnet (https://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wngloss.7WN.html), the adjectives in behavioral cluster or conceptual cluster are the ones you need.